# 2 Separate DACPAC files for test and production

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, database-project, dacpac, sqlproj

I have a VS2015 database project (sqlproj) and I created a lot of test data. I added a parameter to the PostDeploymentScript.sql file and when I need an empty database, I set it false and when I publish it doesn't include test data. When I need a demo database I set it true and when I publish, it also adds test data after deployment.

On the other hand, I want to create two different DACPAC files to prevent manual process and build both of them automatically at once. I searched a little bit and found several articles like this: 
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/data-center/auto-deploy-and-version-your-sql-server-database-with-ssdt/
but I couldn't apply what he said. What am I missing?

I created an (almost) empty database project (Lets say Base.sqlproj) which adds lookup table data after deployment. I created another DB project (Base_Plus_TestData.sqlproj) and added a database reference for the first database.

What I need is, if client needs to deploy empty database I'd like to give them the Base.DACPAC. If client needs to deploy a demo database with test data, I want to give them Base_Plus_TestData.DACPAC.

What should I do for this purpose and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey Jack, A few quick questions - when you have your demo db is the schema exactly the same, just extra data? Also do you have data to deploy in both databases? Finally is it you or customers who run it and how often?

Comment: @EdElliott The schema is completely same. Both have same common lookup data but demo DB has also some imaginary client and sales data. Let's say my product name is HappyCRM, I'd love to create either this DB or the other one as HappyCRM not Base and Base_Plus_TestData

Answer (score 1):

There a couple of extra options over what you already do with a switch to include data, I would choose the first :)

1 - Just give customers who want demo data a script to run after deploying the database (you could do something like use a powershell script/.net app to deploy your data and optionally the data)

2 -  The post deploy script can be edited in a dacpac, you could build your project, copy the dacpac and then edit the post deploy script to include your data on one of the dacpacs.

3 - Create a separate ssdt project that references your main database project with a "same database" reference and the extra post deploy script - wheb you build you will get two dacpacs you can deploy either together if you want data or just the database.

If you also have data in your original dacpac to deploy you will need to copy it into the "with data" dacpac.

Ed

Comment: I think the option Ed gave for #1 is likely your best option. Keep the script separate to populate demo data. Call it when/if needed. You can do the rest, but if the schema is identical otherwise, creating a separate project seems like overkill.  Putting it in the post-deploy will bloat the deploy script quite a bit unnecessarily.

Comment: @EdElliott, My question is not how to deliver test data to the clients, how to do your third option. I already evaluated the first two options but my desire is to give my clients two dacpac files. All other options requires two or more steps or manual processes. On the other hand, with two different dacpac files, they will use either this dacpac or the other one. For the third option, I already added new project, added db reference, selected same database and created two dacpac files but the issue is, the new dacpac file (with the test data) doesn't work properly.Do I misunderstand something?